# XSLT create multiple records with the same ID and name

Tags: xslt

My XML input is:

```
<vb:Report>
        <vb:ID>1111</vb:ID>
        <vb:name>tinker bell</vb:name>
        <vb:experience >
            <vb:title>Consultant1</vb:title>
            <vb:company>Coke</vb:company>
            <vb:startend>04/01 - 04/30</vb:startend>
        </vb:experience>
        <vb:experience>
            <vb:title> Consultant2</vb:title>
            < vb:company>Pepsi</vb:company >
            <vb:startend>05/01 - 04/30</vb:startend>
        </vb:experience>
</vb:report>
```

I need to add 'ID' and 'name' to experience history and write each record on a new line.

Required output:

```
1111 tinker bell Consultant1 Coke 04/01 - 04/30 
1111 tinker bell Consultant2 Pepsi 05/01 - 04/30
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have been your difficulties? The missing namespace declaration was intentional?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your input XML includes the namespace declaration, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XMLRoot xmlns:vb="http://www.vb.org/someNS">
    <vb:Report>
        <vb:ID>1111</vb:ID>
        <vb:name>tinker bell</vb:name>
        <vb:experience >
            <vb:title>Consultant1</vb:title>
            <vb:company>Coke</vb:company>
            <vb:startend>04/01 - 04/30</vb:startend>
        </vb:experience>
        <vb:experience>
            <vb:title> Consultant2</vb:title>
            <vb:company>Pepsi</vb:company >
            <vb:startend>05/01 - 04/30</vb:startend>
        </vb:experience>
    </vb:Report>
</XMLRoot>
```

Then the XSLT transformation to give your desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vb="http://www.vb.org/someNS"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="vb:Report">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="vb:experience"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="vb:experience">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                            preceding-sibling::vb:ID[1],' ',
                            preceding-sibling::vb:name[1],' ',
                            vb:title,' ',
                            vb:company,' ',
                            vb:startend)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can try it here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdwsc/2

Comment: If using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor and `version="2.0"` or `version="3.0"` the `xsl:value-of` can be simplified to simply select the sequence of nodes to be output, the default `separator` is a space character anyway: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdwsc/3